# Download File using webService

Tags: asp.net, web-services

```
[WebMethod()]
    public void GetFileByDocumentNumber(string DocumentNumber)
    {
        string FilePath = GetFile(DocumentNumber);
        string FullPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"]  + FilePath;

        DownloadToBrowser(FullPath);

    }


    private void DownloadToBrowser(string filePath)
    {
        FileInfo file = new FileInfo(filePath);
        Context.Response.Clear();

        Context.Response.ClearHeaders();

        Context.Response.ClearContent();

        Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + file.Name);

        Context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", file.Length.ToString());

        Context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";

        Context.Response.Flush();

        Context.Response.TransmitFile(file.FullName);

        Context.Response.End();
    }
```

I'm using above code for my web service in order to download a file from the server.it's working fine in the local machine but when i host my webservice on a server and try to consume the service it gives the following error

```
Client found response content type of 'text/plain', but expected 'text/xml'.
```

whats the reason for this error?

Comment: FYI, were you aware that ASMX web services (what you're using) are a legacy technology that should not be used for new development?

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace `ContentType` with `application/octet-stream`.

Comment: it gives the error."Client found response content type of 'application/octet-stream', but expected 'text/xml'."

Answer (score 1):

You should have to return a file content via `WebMethod`.

```
[WebMethod()]
public string GetFileByDocumentNumber(string DocumentNumber)
{
   string FilePath = GetFile(DocumentNumber);
   string FullPath = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["FilePath"]  + FilePath;
   return File.ReadAllText(FullPath);
}
```